# Prevent application from entering background, requiring a code to close app

Tags: ios

I would like to add functionality to my iPad app such that, when the home button is pressed and my app is about to enter the background, a message box pops up requesting a code. Only if the correct code is entered will the application go into the background, otherwise the app will not close.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not within Apple's guidelines. You will be looking at creating a jail-broken application to achieve this kind of functionality. If you are interested in jailbreak development consider committing to this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=v3HFF-ebzgSz6aewN1cCiQ2).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no it's not possible.